# Lync 2010 with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, lync-2010, lync-server-2010

As stated [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dcaro/archive/2012/03/13/support-of-sql-server-2012-with-microsoft-lync-2010.aspx) or [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2718721) `SQL Server 2012` is not a supported platform for `Lync 2010`. Yet, is there any workaround?

Didn't find a full solution on the web, so will be posting one which should help some of the people that might face this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some cases should be solved simply by copying the `msdb.sys.sp_dboption` stored procedure, from a previous version of SQL Server, into the `master` database of `SQL Server 2012`, and marking it as a system procedure so it can be executed on any database:

```
USE master
GO
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_dboption
```

There is still something more that can be done if the above is not enough - Install the SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components MSI (it includes the DMO feature)

32 bit, X86 Package - [SQLServer2005_BC.msi](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/1/6/316FADB2-E703-4351-8E9C-E0B36D9D697E/SQLServer2005_BC.msi)
64 bit, X64 Package - [SQLServer2005_BC_x64.msi](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/1/6/316FADB2-E703-4351-8E9C-E0B36D9D697E/SQLServer2005_BC_x64.msi)

Best solution is still the one where you kept Lync 2010 running on SQL Server <= 2008R2 and didn't have to reach this page:)